# How to use multiprocessing in networkx graph layout?

Tags: python, performance, multiprocessing, networkx

I need to improve performance of my python application.
Now im using:

```
nx.spring_layout(G)
```

Now i can wait HOURS while my application running this line of code.

How can i use python module multiprocessing to get better performance in layout of big graph?

Comment: I don't think you can, the multiprocessing code would have to be implemented within networkx for that method.  You might try looking for a more efficient layout implementation. I've no idea if this is useful, but sounds like it might be: https://github.com/bhargavchippada/forceatlas2